# How to make mouse "Middle Click" not to open in new tab on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, instagram

When I want to open a link with **"Middle click"** in a **"new tab"** on **INSTAGRAM**, it doesn't leave the current window and opens inside existing page.

In other websites, the behavior is to open the link in a new tab in the browser.

I saw this in a couple of different websites but it didn't make any sense.

I started to experiment it by logging which key I am clicking via Jquery.

HTML part

```
<a href="#">Clicker</a>
<div id="log">
</div>
```

JS part

```
$('a').mouseup(function (e) {
    var button = 'left click';
    if (e.which === 2) {
        button = 'middle click';
    } else if (e.which == 3) {
        button = 'right click';
    }
    $('#log').append('<span>' + button + '(' + e.which + ')</span><br/>');

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});


$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 3) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/QNUU2/136/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code segment and try. Hope this is what you are asking.

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 2 ){
       alert("middle click")    
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I just don't want someone to leave my "tab"(current windows ) in case the link is clicked with "middle click" of the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is a little bit overkill, but it works!

[Edit] Unfortunately, it seems that `event.preventDefault()` has no effect while being used with "onmousedown \ onauxclick" events!

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" onmousedown='if(event.button === 1){window.location=event.target.getAttribute("href"); event.preventDefault()}'>Visit google (onmousedown)</a> 
<br>
<a href="https://www.google.com" onauxclick='if(event.button === 1){window.location=event.target.getAttribute("href"); event.preventDefault()}'>Visit google (onauxclick)</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works on any `<a>` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<a href="https://www.google.com">Visit google</a> 
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a> 
<br><br>
<div> Div Element 1</div> <br> <div> Div Element 2</div>
<br>
<textarea> ta Element 1</textarea><br><textarea> ta Element 2</textarea><br><textarea rows="50"> ta Element 3</textarea>

<script>

addEventListener("click", Mouse_Button);
addEventListener("mousedown", Mouse_Button);

function Mouse_Button(event){     //________________________

    if (event.button === 1){        //"1" is for Mouse Middle Button
        
        if (event.target.nodeName === "A"){     //if tag "<a></a>" element

            //alert(event.type + " _ " +event.button + " _ " + event.target.nodeName + " _ " + event.target.getAttribute("href"))

        window.open(event.target.getAttribute("href"), "_self");        //"_self" open in same tab

        event.preventDefault();
        //in Chrome and Firefox, Mouse Middle Button is blocked, so links are not open in new tabs (as expected)
        //in Opera and IE9, Mouse Middle Button is not blocked, so links are open in new tabs (Maybe a bug?)

        }
    }    
}

</script>
```